# How can I check test.html.twig exist or not?

Tags: php, symfony, controller, twig, symfony5

I create a controller in Symfony 5:

```
/**
 * @Route ("/{slag}", name="test")
 */
public function index($slag): Response
{
    $test = $slag . '.html.twig';
    return $this->render($test, [
        'title' => 'TEST'
    ]);
}
```

Then create template `test1.html.twig` , `test2.html.twig` and `test3.html.twig`.

When go to address `http://localhost/test1` , show `test1.html.twig` and ... .

But when go to address `http://localhost/test4` , redirect to `http://localhost/` .

I use this for landing pages and don't need many request to database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use try/catch for that.

```php
public function index($slag): Response
{
    $test = $slag . '.html.twig';
    try {
        return $this->render($test, [
            'title' => 'TEST'
        ]);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return $this->redirectToRoute('index');
    }
}
```